# Plugin Installation Error in Craft 3 / PHP Version

Tags: plugins, craft3, installation

I tried to install "Field Manager" Plugin and get following error:

`symfony/console v3.4.4 requires php ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8 -> your PHP version (7.2.1) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.0) does not satisfy that requirement.`

Theres is no config.platform.php anywhere and i have PHP 7.2.1 installed. How can i fix that?

EDIT:
Ok, config.platform.php refers to composer.json entry. I changed it to 7.2 and could install it via command line. Possibly worked via CP too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually when you see that error, Craft was `composer install/update`'d on one environment with say, PHP 7.2.  Composer then pulls in the highest supported dependencies for that environment.

The `composer.lock` file is pushed to a different environment with say, PHP 7.1, creating a conflict the next time Composer needs to run.

You can do this to force Composer to use the lowest common denominator for all of your environments: https://github.com/craftcms/craft/blob/master/composer.json#L34-L36